# raspberry pi fast linux based os

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lightweight

I have made a server with python that does some stuff with databases.

My original plan was to install raspbian, but now that I have it is kind of sluggish.

is there a more lightweight and thus faster linux flavor which runs python and has the ability to run a webbrowser?

Answer (score 2):

There's an RPi category on Distrowatch: [link](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=Raspberry+Pi&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&status=Active)

The Raspberry Pi Foundation also offers [NOOBS](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) for an easier installation. Two of the available options are Arch and Pidora (Fedora).

There's also the eLinux RPi Hub, which lists available distros [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions), and has tons and tons of other info.

If you have some experience with linux, I'd definitely recommend Arch. If you don't, Raspbian or PiDora via NOOBS is probably your best bet.

There's a lot of websites about how to install other distros. If you know which one you want, google it. :)

Every distro is capable of running python, browsers, and servers, so don't worry about that part. :)

Personally, I'm running a server on Raspbian (nginx + sqlite + php), and haven't had problems. Then again, I never use the GUI.

If you're only logging in via the GUI, you should run `raspi-config` and reserve more memory for the video card. You can also overclock the RPi without losing your warranty via `raspi-config`. Finally, if you've been using the default browser, Midori, there's a lot of lighter options.

Answer (score 0):

What about the arch linux variant? see http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/
I don't believe that pidora will be much faster then raspian.

I'm personally content with raspian, but my expectations weren't high.